# Transmission spins but does not engage in any gears

Tags: automatic-transmission

I Purchased a 2002 Mitsubishi Montaro a few months back and at the time of purchase the shift hole in the transfer case for the shift lever was sealed shut with a piece of sheet metal. The other day when I arrived at work and began to back into a parking spot the transmission stopped propelling me backward so I then shifted the car to drive and when I did the guts of the transmission were still spinning yet not engaging even though I had my foot on the break. The gears in the transmission ground to a stop and although I placed the vehicle in drive I went nowhere.Could the transfer case be causing my problem or could it be something else such as the transmission is blown? I sure could use some help on this one.

Comment: Does the transfer case normally have a LOW range?  It's possible the transfer case slipped into neutral.  I would want to figure out why the shift lever for the transfer case is disconnected and blocked off.  Sounds like this issue existed for a while.